# how to control wild card using Regular expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, wildcard

I need java script regular expression to control on the client side.
I have a page with text field need following validation.

1) User allowed to enter two characters after %(ie) %ab or %abcde or %abcdef%

2) % -Not allowed

3) %%-Not allowed

4) %ab-Allowed

5)%ab% allowed

6) %%%-Not allowed

7) %a%- Not allowed.

I am new to write Regular expression. Please help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `/%[a-zA-Z]{2}/`

Comment: If the user is allowed to enter two characters after `%`, why is `%abcde` allowed? That has 5 characters after `%`.

Comment: sorry user can enter two characters or more but not one

Comment: Use a playground: https://regex101.com/r/LjwF4d/1

Comment: Try [`/^(?!.*(?:%%|%[a-z]%))(?!%$)[a-z%]+$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/PttXOh/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Here you go…

```js
var re = /^%[A-Za-z]{2,}%?$/;

console.log(re.test('%')); // false expected
console.log(re.test('%%')); // false expected
console.log(re.test('%ab')); // true expected
console.log(re.test('%ab%')); // true expected
console.log(re.test('%abcde%')); // true expected
console.log(re.test('%abcdef%')); // true expected
console.log(re.test('%%%')); // false expected
console.log(re.test('%a%')); // false expected
```

## Explanation

- `^%` - starts with `%`
- `[A-Za-z]{2,}` - followed by at least 2 (uppercase or lowercase) letters
- `%?$` - with an optional `%` at the end